# Observable LINQ, exists?

Tags: linq

Easy question for those who knows what I'm talking about.

I want to query a source, and keep UI updated all the time without doing it by myself.

There are a few articles out there which talks a bit about it:

http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/dynamic_linq.htm

But my point is, it's there any way to do it, directly from DB sources??

Answer (score 1):

The last post in that article sums it up, overall that method is just listening for the changed event in the ObservableCollection. You'd be safer running a thread-safe timer that updates a collection bound to the view unless you're really itching to implement push functionality.